# Grid Is Missing

Tags: modeling

When I move around to get to the face of the shape I want the grid disappears. Is there a way to get it back because I'm trying to model a car, and I need to layout my blueprint.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You'll find that in the viewport overlays panel.

[image]

Comment: Thank You, Stay Safe!